# where can i find antlib.xml for Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to run `ant build` for Scala. I need to know where can I find "antlib.xml" of Scala. I am using Scala on Ubuntu.

I am getting the error like:

> [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource ${scala.home}/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

Comment: BUILD FAILED
/home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/build.xml:91: Problem: failed to create task or type scalac
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to build recent Scala from source, have a look at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/README.md#using-the-sbt-build how to do that.
Note - the project uses sbt to build, not ant.

If you want to build Scala 2.10, see this instead:
https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.10.x#part-iii-common-use-cases

Comment: I was following this url to write build.xml for scala   https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/98.html and I faced this issue with antlib.xml for scala.